# How can I find out how many bit versions of add-ins are in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, 64-bit, outlook-addin

I am creating 2 plugins as 32 bit and 64 bit. How can I find out how many bits a vsto plugin has.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in :
[Your Project Name] settings -> build -> plateform target (x86 | x64 | Any CPU)

GL

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine the bitness of your code at run-time, use `IntPtr.Size` - 4 in x86 and 8 in x64.

Since Outlook loads your addin, its bitness will always be determined by the bitness of the parent process (outlook.exe). Unless there is a very particular reason to compile your code as x86 or x64, compile it as "Any CPU" - both 32 and 64 bit versions of Outlook will be able to load it.

Comment: IntPtr.Size the outlook' version, I want addin target version

Comment: If your addin is running, it means it was successfully loaded by Outlook, and the bitness of your addin will always match the bitness of Outlook.